# Simple version number checker with wild card notations

Tags: c#

Is there any built-in version checker class in c# that allows wild cards? If not is there any easier way to accomplish this?
Example:

```
bool IsVersionValid(string version, string allowedVersions)
{
    // compares the string and returns if the version is valid.
}
```

If I call:

```
IsVersionValid("1.0", "(1.0,)") --> it should return false.
IsVersionValid("1.0.1", "(1.0,)") --> it should return true.
IsVersionValid("1.0", "[1.0]") --> it should return true.
IsVersionValid("1.0.1", "[1.0]") --> it should return false.
```

Following are the wild card list.

```
Notation: 1.0
Applied rule: x ≥ 1.0   
Description: Minimum version, inclusive

Notation: (1.0,)    
Applied rule: x > 1.0   
Description: Minimum version, exclusive

Notation: [1.0] 
Applied rule: x == 1.0  
Description: Exact version match

Notation: (,1.0]    
Applied rule: x ≤ 1.0   
Description: Maximum version, inclusive

Notation: (,1.0)    
Applied rule: x < 1.0   
Description: Maximum version, exclusive

Notation: [1.0,2.0] 
Applied rule: 1.0 ≤ x ≤ 2.0 
Description: Exact range, inclusive

Notation: (1.0,2.0) 
Applied rule: 1.0 < x < 2.0 
Description: Exact range, exclusive

Notation: [1.0,2.0) 
Applied rule: 1.0 ≤ x < 2.0 
Description: inclusive minimum and exclusive maximum version

Notation: (1.0) 
Applied rule: invalid
Description: invalid
```

Comment: This question is not clear to me. What are your inputs and what is your desired output?

Comment: I see. I don't think there is anything built-in that does exactly this, but you may be interested in the [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class, which will do at least some of the work.

Comment: Just a string parsing problem, what's your difficulty?

Comment: If you want it in the hardcoded string way why don't you just split the version at the `.` and then compare it as interger?

Comment: @JohnWu, I am aware of the Version class. It seems I have to parse the string to validate. Thanks anyway.